# Fluid motion videos

Tags: fluid-dynamics, resource-recommendations, biophysics

I am looking for references to papers and research problems involving fluid mechanics, and in particular animal/plant/bacteria locomotion, that could be illustrated by showing a video like [these](http://gfm.aps.org/). It's for a slide presentation meant for 11 year old students. Could you point me towards something?

Comment: Hi usumdelphini. Resource recommendation and reference questions are restricted on Phys.SE for various reasons, e.g., they tend to be list questions and _primarily opinion-based._ I'm closing this question as a _duplicate,_ not because it is an exact duplicate, but to point you in the right direction.